# JQuery Changing images on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following Jquery code i have two issues with this please help. thanks in advance.

What does this code do?
Changes image on mouseover (i.e. image) (image frames keep on changing give a gaming effect or video effect 1-100)

Issues?
1) I want to run this on button hover i.e. `#btn-forward` for forward & `#btn-back` for back but its not working for button for strange reason that i don't know (i have just handled move forward only in code) please help.
2) I want to create break points after every 10 frames where user is stoped showed some links etc and can continue from that point.
3) This not running smooth any suggestions for that?

Note: if i am not clear do let me know...thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var images = [];

    images[0] = "img/1.jpg";
    images[1] = "img/2.jpg";
    images[2] = "img/3.jpg";
    images[3] = "img/4.jpg";
    images[4] = "img/5.jpg";
    images[5] = "img/6.jpg";
    images[6] = "img/7.jpg";
    images[7] = "img/8.jpg";
    images[8] = "img/9.jpg";
    images[9] = "img/10.jpg";

    images[10] = "img/11.jpg";
    images[11] = "img/12.jpg";
    images[12] = "img/13.jpg";
    images[13] = "img/14.jpg";
    images[14] = "img/15.jpg";
    images[15] = "img/16.jpg";
    images[16] = "img/17.jpg";
    images[17] = "img/18.jpg";  
    images[18] = "img/19.jpg";
    images[19] = "img/20.jpg";

    images[20] = "img/21.jpg";
    images[21] = "img/22.jpg";
    images[22] = "img/23.jpg";
    images[23] = "img/24.jpg";
    images[24] = "img/25.jpg";
    images[25] = "img/26.jpg";
    images[26] = "img/27.jpg";
    images[27] = "img/28.jpg";
    images[28] = "img/29.jpg";
    images[29] = "img/30.jpg";

    images[30] = "img/31.jpg";
    images[31] = "img/32.jpg";
    images[32] = "img/33.jpg";
    images[33] = "img/34.jpg";
    images[34] = "img/35.jpg";
    images[35] = "img/36.jpg";  
    images[36] = "img/37.jpg";
    images[37] = "img/38.jpg";
    images[38] = "img/39.jpg";
    images[39] = "img/40.jpg";

    images[40] = "img/41.jpg";
    images[41] = "img/42.jpg";
    images[42] = "img/43.jpg";
    images[43] = "img/44.jpg";
    images[44] = "img/45.jpg";
    images[45] = "img/46.jpg";
    images[46] = "img/47.jpg";
    images[47] = "img/48.jpg";
    images[48] = "img/49.jpg";
    images[49] = "img/50.jpg";

    images[50] = "img/51.jpg";
    images[51] = "img/52.jpg";
    images[52] = "img/53.jpg";
    images[53] = "img/54.jpg";  
    images[54] = "img/55.jpg";
    images[55] = "img/56.jpg";
    images[56] = "img/57.jpg";
    images[57] = "img/58.jpg";
    images[58] = "img/59.jpg";
    images[59] = "img/60.jpg";

    images[60] = "img/61.jpg";
    images[61] = "img/62.jpg";
    images[62] = "img/63.jpg";
    images[63] = "img/64.jpg";
    images[64] = "img/65.jpg";
    images[65] = "img/66.jpg";
    images[66] = "img/67.jpg";
    images[67] = "img/68.jpg";
    images[68] = "img/69.jpg";
    images[69] = "img/70.jpg";

    images[70] = "img/71.jpg";
    images[71] = "img/72.jpg";
    images[72] = "img/73.jpg";
    images[73] = "img/74.jpg";  
    images[74] = "img/75.jpg";
    images[75] = "img/76.jpg";
    images[76] = "img/77.jpg";
    images[77] = "img/78.jpg";
    images[78] = "img/79.jpg";
    images[79] = "img/80.jpg";

    images[80] = "img/81.jpg";
    images[81] = "img/82.jpg";
    images[82] = "img/83.jpg";
    images[83] = "img/84.jpg";
    images[84] = "img/85.jpg";
    images[85] = "img/86.jpg";
    images[86] = "img/87.jpg";
    images[87] = "img/88.jpg";
    images[88] = "img/89.jpg";
    images[89] = "img/90.jpg";

    images[90] = "img/91.jpg";
    images[91] = "img/92.jpg";
    images[92] = "img/93.jpg";
    images[93] = "img/94.jpg";
    images[94] = "img/95.jpg";
    images[95] = "img/96.jpg";
    images[96] = "img/97.jpg";
    images[97] = "img/98.jpg";
    images[98] = "img/99.jpg";
    images[99] = "img/100.jpg";
    images[100] = "img/101.jpg";    

    var loop;
    var i = 0;

    var counter = $("#counter");

    $('.video-thumb img, #btn-forward').mouseover(function() {
        var image = this;
        loop = setInterval(function() {

            if (i < images.length - 1) {
                i++;
                $(image).attr('src',images[i]);
            } else {
                i = 0;
                $(image).attr('src',images[i]);
            } 
            counter.html(i);
        }, 100); 

    }).mouseout(function() {
        clearInterval(loop);
        /*i = 0;*/
        $(this).attr('src', images[i]); 
        counter.html(i);
    });

});

</script>


</head>

<body>
<div class="video-thumb"> 
    <img src="img/1.jpg" />
</div>
<input type="submit" id="btn-forward" value="Forward" />
<input type="submit" id="btn-back" value="Back" />
<div id="counter">0</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really don't need that array.

Comment: _"its not working for button"_ - That's because you haven't spelled "forward" consistently. The attribute `id="btn-forward"` has the correct spelling, with an "a" after the "w", but the `value` and your jQuery selector spell it incorrectly with an "o". And no, you _really_ don't need that array...

Comment: It almost feels like there is a pattern somewhere in that array..

Comment: sorry for missed spell...originally the code was ok while pasting here code i come know that forward is spelled therefor due carelessness i have changed some where while leaving other...sorry again and your advice is highly appreciated and array can be skipped as well...| But i have checked all code there is no misspells (code on my local machine) but button mouseover is not working properly. On button over its increments count but not changing the frames. only counter increments but frames remains static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd do that like so :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var images = 100, // number of images
        loop,
        i = 0;

    $('#btn-forward, #btn-back').on({
        mouseenter: function(e) {
            i = parseInt( $('.video-thumb img').prop('src').replace(/\D+/,''), 10);
            loop = setInterval(function() {
                i = e.target.id == 'btn-forward' ? (i>images?1:i+1) : (i<2?(images+1):i-1);
                $('.video-thumb img').prop('src', 'img/'+(i)+'.jpg');
                $('#counter').text(i);
            }, 100); 
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            clearInterval(loop)
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6JmZf/3/)

The array is not neccessary as you can use an incrementing variable instead.

Also note that you're using `forword` and `forward` as ID's and in selectors, and you need decide which one it is !

**EDIT:**

to preload all the images, you can add a small preloading loop:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var images = 100,
        loop,
        i = 0;

    for(var j=1; j<102; j++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'img/'+j+'.jpg'
    }

    $('#btn-forward, #btn-back').on({
        mouseenter: function(e) {
            i = parseInt( $('.video-thumb img').prop('src').replace(/\D+/,''), 10);
            loop = setInterval(function() {
                i = e.target.id == 'btn-forward' ? (i>images?1:i+1) : (i<2?(images+1):i-1);
                $('.video-thumb img').prop('src', 'img/'+(i)+'.jpg');
                $('#counter').text(i);
                console.log(i)
            }, 100); 
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            clearInterval(loop)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: how can we load all images at once to avoid distortion or discontinuity in the video? should i ask a new question or you can help me here? thanks

Comment: @AamirShahzad - added a preloader to the answer.

Comment: well thanks a lot @adeneo...still i can observe distortion i am moving about 200 images...is there any way to load all images and make user wait until all loads up so that user may enjoy whole video running smoothly...like we see real videos they first loads up and then run...

Answer (score 1):

Well this is how you would loop through the array:

```
<script>

    var num  = 100;

    for(var i = 0; i <= num; i++){
        console.log("inc : " + i);
    }


    for(var k = num ; k >= 0; k--) {
        console.log("dec : " + k);
    }

</script>
```

The first loop `increments`, and the 2nd one `decrements`

Comment: Huh? The OP's code already loops through the array. (Also, why `i++` but not `k--`?)

Comment: @nnnnnn  Yes, forwards, but he wants to add a back option, which means decrementing through the array ;-). Yes it should be `k--`, fixed.

Comment: Yes, but a `for` loop doesn't work for the OP's purpose. It has to be some sort of `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` based "loop" for the animation to work.